# Why do my MySQL queries get much faster when I open the Operations page on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have noticed a very weird behavior with MySQL 5.5. I do have an InnoDB table of about 200,000 rows with 3 indexes. The query I use pulls the last 20 rows from the table in a couple of milliseconds. After a few days this query gets much slower and takes about one second. But when I open the Operations page on phpMyAdmin for that table, the query gets back to being very fast.

I have tested this several times and it is consistent. Once the queries have become slow they remain consistently slow until I open the Operations page of phpMyAdmin. I don't do anything there. I simply open that page. I want to find out what is going on. What does phpMyAdmin do to the table when I open the Operations page? I am on MySQL 5.5 and have no way to change that (hosted and managed server).

I do believe that the issue is connected with InnoDB, because this table was MyISAM before and I have not noticed this behavior earlier.

Comment: To see which queries are sent by phpMyAdmin, set $cfg['DBG']['sql'] to true in config.inc.php, then use the Operations page.

Comment: And show us that SQL.

Comment: As noted I am on a managed server (with IONOS) and afaik cannot change the phpMyAdmin configuration file config.inc.php.